# Migrate from free and paid versions app to one app with in-app purchases

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I did big mistake with monetisation my app in Google Play.
I separated my app to 2 versions (with different applicationId), but now I would like to have one app with in-app purchases to Pro version or something like unlocker. 
I have a lot of downloads my pro version app so I can't just remove it from Google Play.
Does anyone faced with this problem ? Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely integrate both apps ( Search on stackoverflow for integrating both apps ), but that will not solve your paid users approach.

Here is what I would do

**STEP 1** : Implement in-app purchase in FREE app ( Test it - make it live )

**STEP 2** : Update prod app ( Show message to users to migrate to FREE app ). Since you have only paid users- it's safe to give each user a promo-code, you need to work on some logic in paid app for creating such unique codes per user - see this link for creating promo codes which can be redeemed once https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html#workflow

**STEP 3**: All Paid users redeems promo codes in free app.

**STEP 4** :  Remove paid app from google play store

**PS :** If you have local files , data etc with paid users, you still need to migrate them to free app, you can use shared resource, server side coding or simply using ContentProviders

I don't think there is any other easy way to do this.