# Will switch from paid app to monthly subscription effects users who purchased the app

Tags: android, google-play, subscription

The app is currently a paid app on google play. Now I want to change it to a monthly subscription with 3 days free trial. The flow in my idea for the new app version would be:

1/ Check if the user has already purchased the app by license checker LVL. (I will use the privacy checker by Javier Santos)
2/If they purchased. Let them use. If not, let them use the trial then ask for a subscription.

My concern is: Once I change it to free trial, will the license checker recognize the free trial as purchased? If it does then my flow would be a disaster.

I appreciate any idea for my case. Thank you for your time.

Comment: once app published as paid you cannot change to free or viceversa. You want to create a new free app with subscription and implement a mechanism to get paid users migrated to new app .. one approach as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373388/migrate-from-free-and-paid-versions-app-to-one-app-with-in-app-purchases/42383829#42383829

Comment: I see in the price section of the app, it has the option to change to free. (It warns that I cannot change to paid app), Is it what I'm looking for? Update to subscription then change it to free with that button?

Comment: you are right.. sorry didn't realize you can change from paid to free. Yes update with subscription code and then change it to FREE

Comment: Guess I know what to do now, thank you @AmodGokhale!